# Uncaught ReferenceError: mostrarFrase is not defined at HTMLHeadingElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html5

hice un arreglo que contiene diferentes frases, despues cree una funcion para que cada vez que el usuario de un clic cambie la frase aleatoriamente, pero marca el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a continuacion el codigo:
*codigo corregido

```
const frases = [
  'frase1',
  'frase2',
  'frase3',
];

//funcion
const mostrarFrase = (titulo) => {
let frase = frases[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]; 
titulo.innerHTML = `"${frase}"`;
}
```

codigo HTML:

```
<h2 onclick="mostrarFrase(this)">frases</h2>
```

Actualizacion 1:
se solucionaron los errores de sintaxis,
ahora este es el error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualizacion 2:
para corregir el error anterior se debe reemplazar esta linea donde se incluye el script:

```
<script type="module" src="./js/app.js"></script>
```

por esta:

```
<script src="./js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sucede que al comienzo estás ejecutando `mostrarFrase()` sin ningún parámetro, y `titulo` te devolverá `undefined`, y por ello el error. Sólo debes borrar `mostrarFrase()`. También coloca las comas delante de cada elemento en tu array, y faltaría un `=` despues de `frases` en la primera línea. Sería así: `const frases = ['frase1','frase2','frase3'];`. [demo](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/wvRJrzd).

Comment: muchas gracias Cris eh corregido los puntos que me comentas y eh visto la demo que me compartes y se soluciona el problema, pero ahora me lanza un nuevo error:  Uncaught ReferenceError: mostrarFrase is not defined
    at HTMLHeadingElement.onclick (index.html:48:42)